# Получить список модулей 64-битного процесса из 32-битной программы

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, процесс

В своей программе мне нужно получить список модулей загруженных в любой другой процесс. Сама программа 32-битная. Для получения списка модулей использую функцию EnumProcessModulesEx(). Для 64-битных процессов список модулей она не возвращает.

Пока я думаю сделать отдельный 64-битный процесс и через него обмениваться данными. Написать функцию-обертку, которая будет отсылать запрос в этот процесс, наподобие "получить список модулей такого-то процесса", а затем пересылать результат в мою программу.

Ещё вариант - COM Surrogate, но ничего толком не нашёл.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть ещё варианты? Либо, может есть простой вариант, без этих заморочек.

P.S. Вариант скомпилировать программу под 64 бита не предлагать).

Comment: Скомпилируйте программу под 64 бита. в 2018 году не делать этого печально

Comment: Задача стоит намного шире, и я уже написал, этот вариант не предлагать.

Comment: Портируйте на 64, это окупится. А пока - просто сделайте себе маленькое приложение, которое будет собрано на 64бита и будет собирать нужную информацию. Само приложение может быть консольным и выводить прямо в стандартный вывод.

Comment: @KoVadim: Тогда будет проблема в получении списка модулей 32-битного процесса.

Comment: а 32битный код может само основное приложение обрабатывать. Или ещё один модуль для 32бит:)

Comment: @VladD, в 64-битном приложении можно спокойно получать список модулей 32-битного процесса.

Comment: @IvanSh.: Хм, не знал. Тогда и правда, простейшее решение было бы перейти на 64 бита, да.

Comment: @KoVadim, мне в дальнейшем в сторонний процесс надо будет делать внедрение своей dll, так что компиляция в 64-бита не решит проблему, так как в этом случае надо делать "прослойку", чтобы внедриться уже в 32-битный процесс.

Comment: @VladD, мне в дальнейшем в сторонний процесс надо будет делать внедрение своей dll, так что компиляция в 64-бита не решит проблему, так как в этом случае надо делать "прослойку", чтобы внедриться уже в 32-битный процесс.

Comment: @IvanSh, 64-битная архитектура обратно совместима с 32. Т.е. что работает на 32, скорее всего будет работать в 64.

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать код, который привели тут http://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread2168269.html.
*Судя по тексту вопроса, ответ и был дан для Вас.*

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801517/how-to-enum-modules-in-a-64bit-process-from-a-32bit-wow-process/44502139#44502139

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать это путем чтения Process Environment Block (PEB) с помощью  функций Native API *NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64* и *NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <windows.h>

#define NT_SUCCESS(x) ((x) >= 0)

// Namespace is present Not to collide with "winbase.h"
// definition of PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS and others.
namespace sys
{

typedef enum _PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    ProcessBasicInformation,
    ProcessQuotaLimits,
    ProcessIoCounters,
    ProcessVmCounters,
    ProcessTimes,
    ProcessBasePriority,
    ProcessRaisePriority,
    ProcessDebugPort,
    ProcessExceptionPort,
    ProcessAccessToken,
    ProcessLdtInformation,
    ProcessLdtSize,
    ProcessDefaultHardErrorMode,
    ProcessIoPortHandlers,
    ProcessPooledUsageAndLimits,
    ProcessWorkingSetWatch,
    ProcessUserModeIOPL,
    ProcessEnableAlignmentFaultFixup,
    ProcessPriorityClass,
    ProcessWx86Information,
    ProcessHandleCount,
    ProcessAffinityMask,
    ProcessPriorityBoost,
    MaxProcessInfoClass
} PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PPROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Structs.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION64 {
    ULONGLONG Reserved1;
    ULONGLONG PebBaseAddress;
    ULONGLONG Reserved2[2];
    ULONGLONG UniqueProcessId;
    ULONGLONG Reserved3;
} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION64;

typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA64 {
    ULONG Length;
    BOOLEAN Initialized;
    ULONGLONG SsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY64 InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY64 InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY64 InInitializationOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA64, *PPEB_LDR_DATA64;

// Structure is cut down to ProcessHeap.
typedef struct _PEB64 {
    BOOLEAN InheritedAddressSpace;
    BOOLEAN ReadImageFileExecOptions;
    BOOLEAN BeingDebugged;
    BOOLEAN Spare;
    ULONGLONG Mutant;
    ULONGLONG ImageBaseAddress;
    ULONGLONG LoaderData;
    ULONGLONG ProcessParameters;
    ULONGLONG SubSystemData;
    ULONGLONG ProcessHeap;
} PEB64;

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING64 {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    ULONGLONG Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING64;

typedef struct _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64 {
    LIST_ENTRY64 InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY64 InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY64 InInitializationOrderModuleList;
    ULONGLONG BaseAddress;
    ULONGLONG EntryPoint;
    DWORD64 SizeOfImage;
    UNICODE_STRING64 FullDllName;
    UNICODE_STRING64 BaseDllName;
    ULONG Flags;
    SHORT LoadCount;
    SHORT TlsIndex;
    LIST_ENTRY64 HashTableEntry;
    ULONGLONG TimeDateStamp;
} LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64, *PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64;

}  // namespace sys

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function prototypes.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64)(
    IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    ULONG ProcessInformationClass,
    OUT PVOID ProcessInformation,
    IN ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
    OUT PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL);

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *_NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64)(
    IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    IN DWORD64 BaseAddress,
    OUT PVOID Buffer,
    IN ULONG64 Size,
    OUT PDWORD64 NumberOfBytesRead);


//Functions to print error messages
void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction,WCHAR* buf) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Print the error message 
    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    swprintf(buf,L"%s returned error 0x%x: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}

void RaiseError(LPTSTR lpszFunction){
    WCHAR buf[1024]={0};
    ErrorMes(lpszFunction,buf);
    std::wcout << buf << std::endl;
    throw std::exception("WINAPI call failed");
}

#ifndef WIN32
#   error "This application must be built as an x86 executable"
#endif

#define GET_FUNC_ADDR(name) _##name name = (_##name)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), #name)

#define CHECK_ERROR(clause, func) if (!(clause)) { RaiseError(func); }

namespace
{

struct close_on_exit
{
    close_on_exit(HANDLE ptr)
        : ptr_(ptr)
    { };

    ~close_on_exit()
    {
        if (ptr_)
        {
            ::CloseHandle(ptr_);
            ptr_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

private:
    HANDLE ptr_;
};

// Create C++ string based on unicode data 
std::wstring CreateString(std::vector<uint8_t> &raw_bytes)
{
    std::vector<uint16_t> unicode(raw_bytes.size() >> 1, 0);
    memcpy(unicode.data(), raw_bytes.data(), raw_bytes.size());    

    const std::wstring wide_string(unicode.begin(), unicode.end());    

    return wide_string;
}

//Open process handle by its ID
void *get_handle(uint32_t id)
{

    HANDLE handle = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, id);   
    CHECK_ERROR(NULL != handle, L"OpenProcess");    

    return handle;
}

void check_if_process_is_x64(HANDLE handle)
{
    BOOL is_wow64_process = TRUE;
    CHECK_ERROR(::IsWow64Process(handle, &is_wow64_process), L"IsWow64Process");

    if(FALSE != is_wow64_process) throw std::exception( "Target process is not x64 one");
}

std::vector<uint8_t> read_mem(HANDLE handle, uint64_t address, uint32_t length)
{
    if(handle == NULL)throw std::exception("Process handle is null");

    std::vector<uint8_t> data(length, 0);

    GET_FUNC_ADDR(NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64);

    NTSTATUS status = NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64(handle, address, data.data(), data.size(), FALSE);

    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
        std::wcout << L"NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64 status: " << status <<std::endl;
        throw std::exception("NT API call failed");
    }

    return data;
}

void read_pbi(HANDLE handle, sys::PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION64 &pbi)
{
    if(handle == NULL)throw std::exception("Process handle is null");

    GET_FUNC_ADDR(NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64);

    NTSTATUS status = NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64(handle, sys::ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), NULL);

    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
        std::wcout << L"NtQueryInformationProcess status: " << status << std::endl;
        throw std::exception("NT API call failed");
    }
}

std::vector<uint8_t> read_peb_data(HANDLE handle)
{
    sys::PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION64 pbi = { 0 };
    read_pbi(handle, pbi);

    return read_mem(handle, pbi.PebBaseAddress, sizeof(sys::PEB64));
}

//Prints 64-bit process modules
bool get_modules_load_order_via_peb(HANDLE handle)
{    

    std::vector<uint8_t> read_peb = read_peb_data(handle);
    sys::PEB64 *peb = (sys::PEB64 *)read_peb.data();

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Read memory from pointer to loader data structures.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    std::vector<uint8_t> read_peb_ldr_data = read_mem(handle, (uintptr_t)peb->LoaderData, sizeof(sys::PEB_LDR_DATA64));
    sys::PEB_LDR_DATA64 *peb_ldr_data = (sys::PEB_LDR_DATA64 *)read_peb_ldr_data.data();
    sys::PEB_LDR_DATA64 *loader_data = (sys::PEB_LDR_DATA64 *)peb->LoaderData;

    const uintptr_t addr_of_ptr_to_first_ldr_module = (uintptr_t)loader_data
        + ((uintptr_t)&loader_data->InLoadOrderModuleList - (uintptr_t)&loader_data->Length);

    ULONGLONG address = peb_ldr_data->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink;

    uint32_t counter = 1;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Traversing loader data structures.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    do
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> read_ldr_table_entry = read_mem(handle, address, sizeof(sys::LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64));

        sys::LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64 *ldr_table_entry = (sys::LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64 *)read_ldr_table_entry.data();

        std::vector<uint8_t> unicode_name = read_mem(handle, ldr_table_entry->BaseDllName.Buffer, ldr_table_entry->BaseDllName.MaximumLength);
        std::wstring name = CreateString(unicode_name);

        std::wcout  << name << std::endl;   

        ldr_table_entry = (sys::LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY64 *)read_ldr_table_entry.data();
        address = (uintptr_t)ldr_table_entry->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink;
    } while (addr_of_ptr_to_first_ldr_module != address);       

    return true;
}

}  // namespace


/********************************************************************************/
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       

    try
    {
        HANDLE handle = get_handle(2564);
        close_on_exit auto_close_handle(handle);

        check_if_process_is_x64(handle);

        std::wcout << L"------------- Modules: ------------------------\n";
        get_modules_load_order_via_peb(handle);
        std::wcout << L"-----------------------------------------------\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::wcout << L"\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
        std::wcout << "Exception occurred: " << e.what();
        std::wcout << L"\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Источник: [ответ greenpiece на stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502139/8674428)